# How to reset this span's text generated from a regularExpressionValidator at asp with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this html block at an aspx page:

```
<td class="NormalBold">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSendSummary" ClientIDMode="Static"  CssClass="NormalTextBox"   style="width: 170px;" Enabled="False" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtSendSummaryValidEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ControlToValidate="txtSendSummary" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"/>
    </td>
```

I tried to reset the "*" with :

```
 document.getElementById('txtSendSummaryValidEmail').value = "";
```

But still "*" is there!
How i can reset this span of the validator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here. Firstly `span` elements do not have a `value`, so you'll need to change that to use `innerText` instead:

```
document.getElementById('txtSendSummaryValidEmail').innerText = "";
```

The second problem you may face is that ASP.NET ensures that `id` attributes on elements like these are unique by prefixing them. Where you're declaring your ID as `txtSendSummaryValidEmail`, the final result is going to look something like `c001_c001_txtSendSummaryValidEmail`.

Depending on which browsers you need to support, your best bet may be to use CSS's [substring-matching attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) to match the end of the ID within a `querySelector` method:

```
document.querySelector('[id$="txtSendSummaryValidEmail"]').innerText = "";
```